# How to verify multiple CSS attributes in one method

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a newbie setting up a python selenium framework and am wondering if I should collect and verify CSS attributes more tidily?

I currently have the verify css function set up in the base page and these methods which define the individual css attributes in the code below (see image_thumb & image_height):

```
class BrokenImagePage(BasePage):
    _broken_image =  {"by": By.XPATH, "value": "//img[1]"}
    _placeholder_image = {"by": By.XPATH, "value": "//img[3]"}
    _title = {"by" : By.XPATH, "value": "//div[@class='example']/h3"}

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self._visit("/broken_images")
        assert self._is_displayed(self._title)

    def image_present (self):
        return self._is_displayed(self._broken_image)

    def image_thumb (self):
        return self._wait_for_is_displayed(self._placeholder_image, 5)

    def image_height (self):
        return self._verify_css_value(self._placeholder_image, 'height')

    def image_width (self):
        return self._verify_css_value(self._placeholder_image, 'width')
```

Then I assert against the attribute in my test like so:

```
 def test_image_css(self, images):
    assert images.image_height() == '90px'
    assert images.image_width() == '120px'
```

This doesn't seem very efficient to me. Could I collect all the attributes in one method and assert against those in a better way?

Comment: It's related to the context of your task. Use OOP principles.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov Yep, thank you. Woke with a fresh brain and sorted it almost immediately :-)